couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig with Intel Graphics
I'm running Endeavouros 6.6.48-1-lts. After updating the aur yesterday (around 10 pm), I kept having an issue with opening kitty, which, after doing further reading, got me to this command: glxinfo, which outputs:
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

I can't figure out how to fix this issue (I'm not even really sure what this means, as I've only been using Arch-based distros for about two years). I'm using X with no configuration on my end.
Other potentially useful info:
Output of lshw -c display:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raptor Lake-U [Intel Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: simpledrmdrmfb
       physical id: 4
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1200

Output of ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd1375a000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x000071a9088e3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x000071a9087a2000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x000071a9085b1000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x000071a9084f9000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLX.so.0 (0x000071a9084c7000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x000071a90849c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000071a9089c4000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x000071a908495000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x000071a90848d000)

I've already installed all the required packages from the wiki.

Which (AUR) packages did you update? Did you update all official packages before with pacman -Syu?

Take a look at the Arch Linux Forums page [SOLVED] glxinfo Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig. Doesn't mention kitty, but if your glxinfo error refers to the underlying problem, it seems that it might be helpful. The page indicates that to resolve the glxinfo error, "just do a full system upgrade with reinstalling mesa and vulkan."
Full disclosure: I use neither Arch nor an Arch-based distro, so I can't really say if this will help or not.

There is an additional comment at the end of the page: check your Xorg.0.log file for indications of a partial update.
